# Redirect program output to file with line number limit

Tags: logs

Is it possible to redirect program output to file, but with maximum lines limit, for example 4 lines limit:

```
./program | save 4 out.txt
```

The `./program` will continue giving output (maybe one line or more) every few seconds, but only 4 most recent/last lines will be saved to `out.txt`. Is there already a `save` program that could do this? (or I should make it manually)

Comment: So the most recent 4 lines are always in out.txt? Or the most recent *group* of 4 lines...?

Comment: yes, only the most recent 4 lines in `out.txt`

Comment: Yeah, you can do it, but you wouldn't want to. It's expensive in a lot of ways - especially disk i/o if you're talking about a regular file.

Comment: I'll to save it on the `/tmp` (ramfs) and symlink it to `/var/www` directory

Comment: It would probably be 'better' to simply use `./program > out.txt` and when you need to look at the file, use `tail -4 out.txt`.  The `tail` command won't read the whole file each time; it will seek to the end and then 'scan backwards' to find the last four lines.

Comment: no, because I want to serve the tail part on the webserver..

Answer (score 2):

This could be a good job for the shell's `read` builtin - as long as your input is text, that is, and doesn't contain any `\0NUL`s. I say this because, though it is often terribly inefficient for file work when compared with other standard utilities, using a shell builtin would likely be better than repeatedly forking another process. And you won't get much efficiency anyway because the only way to do this *(that I know of)* is to repeatedly `open()` your output file - unless you can be very sure of the number of bytes per line *(which might be assured with a few chained `dd`s in a pipeline, I guess)*. In any case, the following will work:

```sh
###seq used for demo###
seq 3 |( set --
while IFS= read -r l
do    set -- "$@" "$l"
      shift "$(($#>4))"
      printf %s\\n "$@" >/tmp/4_lines
###demo commands###
      printf '\n###4_lines CONTENTS###\n'
      cat </tmp/4_lines
      printf '###END###\n'
###end demo###
done)
```

So if I do the above as written this is written to the `while` loop's stdout:

```
###4_lines CONTENTS###
1
###END###

###4_lines CONTENTS###
1
2
###END###

###4_lines CONTENTS###
1
2
3
###END###
```

But if I hand `seq` 20, for example, it prints the above then:

```
###4_lines CONTENTS###
1
2
3
4
###END###

###4_lines CONTENTS###
2
3
4
5
###END###
```

...all the way up to...

```
###4_lines CONTENTS###
16
17
18
19
###END###

###4_lines CONTENTS###
17
18
19
20
###END###
```

It will go on like that until the input pipe is closed - just round-robining its arg array and overwriting `/tmp/4_lines` with the array's contents each time an input line is `read`. If you wanted the lines in reverse order - so the first line is the last line read in, you could change the `printf` line to:

```
printf %s\\n ${4+"$4"} ${3+"$3"} ${2+"$2"} "$1" >/tmp/4_lines
```

...which would print like...

```
###4_lines CONTENTS###
1
###END###

###4_lines CONTENTS###
2
1
###END###

###4_lines CONTENTS###
3
2
1
###END###
```

...through...

```
###4_lines CONTENTS###
19
18
17
16
###END###

###4_lines CONTENTS###
20
19
18
17
###END###
```

...without risking any difficulties with `$IFS` and/or unintentional globs on the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you're asking by running `./program | tail -n 4 > out.txt`. If not, then I'm not understanding what you're asking.

Comment: when `./program` gives output every few seconds, would the `out.txt` always has the last 4 lines?

Comment: No, `out.txt` would only have content once `./program` completes.

Answer (score 0):

The `save` program could be something like this:

```c
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
  if(argc<=2) {
    cerr << "First param must be a number, second must be a file" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  int max = atoi(argv[1]);
  if(max <= 0) return -2;
  string lines[max];
  int cmax = 1;
  int z = 0;
  while(true) {
    getline(cin,lines[z]);
    ++z;
    z %= max;
    ofstream fo(argv[2]);
    for(int x=0;x<cmax;++x) {
      fo << lines[(x+cmax-z)%cmax] << endl;
    }
    fo.close();
    if(cmax<max) ++cmax;
  }
}
```

Compile using `g++ save.cpp -o save`

Comment: The argument check should be `if (argc != 3)`.  It is conventional to write a usage message, too: `cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " numlines file" << endless;`

Comment: Also note that using a VLA (variable length array) in C++ is a GNU extension.

Comment: You should also check for EOF somewhere; probably using `while (getline(cin, lines[2]))`.

Comment: (And apologies for the `endless`; I didn't notice the tablet autocompleting `endl` into `endless`.)